# Using ExitAPI in a HTML5 ad banner with parameters

Tags: javascript, html, google-ads-api, double-click, ads

I have created a banner for Adwords, using HTML5 with a form element, which accepts few inputs, like your preffered color, type, etc.
The whole banner is not clickable, only the submit button, which I achieved by adding "onclick="ExitApi.exit()"" to the button.

All of this works fine, but now my question is, how flexible is this ExitApi?

Whenever I click the submit button, I want to append the generated parameters to the final url, which is set through AdWords.

Using the adwords preview I can see that during the redirect the last parameter is 'adurl' which contains my final destination. 
Editing this manually and just typing in the parameters helps me achieve what I want, but how would I be able to append using the ExitApi js library, if that's even possible?

I also tried using a CTA through GWD using something like `'gwd.actions.gwdDoubleclick.exitOverride('gwd-ad', 'clickTag', 'http://example.com/index.php?some=var'+params, true, true);'`, which hasn't worked and is also limiting as it forces the developer to set the url through the banner.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Thanks,
Edvinas

Comment: We're having the exact same issue here, did you find anything in the meantime?

Comment: Hi Dorian, after doing some research, turns out Adwords policy is against having forms in their banners. They might be working on a fix for this, I am not too sure. Strangely enough you can build a flash banner with a form, but Flash will no longer be supported starting September 1st (maybe that's the reason). There are different platforms that accept this. I managed to achieve what I wanted through AdForm platform.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is stuck on this aswell, just an update.

I have contacted Google Adwords Support about this and here's their response:

> Unfortunately, multiple exit URLs are not supported in the AdWords environment. Doubleclick, on the other hand, can handle them.
>
> https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/4450409
>
> There are many nice components in GWD which could use different URLs, but they can't be deployed in AdWords.