# Adwords ExitApit url parameters

Tags: url, parameters, google-ads-api

I have created a banner for Adwords, using HTML5 and a form element.
Only a part of the banner is clickable, which I achieved by adding `onclick="ExitApi.exit()"` to the button.

Question: How do I add url parameters to the ExitApi.exit(), like `example.com/page?a=1&b=2&c=3`?

This might be a duplicate question from [Using ExitAPI in a HTML5 ad banner with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960575). However this question is related to multiple exit URLs, which are not supported in the AdWords.

We use 1 Exit domain with variable parameters.